# Magento 2: Unable to get item_id while event "sales_order_save_after" is trigger

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, magento2.2.6

I need the product item id while `sales_order_save_after`  event call. 
I try the following code. I am not able to get the item_id

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) 
{
    $this->logger->info($orderItem->getId()); // Not return anything
    $this->logger->info($orderItem->getData()['item_id']); // Not return anything                   
}
```

Nothing provide item_id . how to get the item id while `sales_order_save_after` calls. I am using Magento 2.2.6

My event is working perfectly. I can get all the remaining details. expect order_id and item_id

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: Is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_orderFactory;

public function __costruct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
){
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
    $orderData = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    foreach($orderData->getAllItems() as $orderItem) 
    {
        echo $orderItem->getItemId();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am testing . i will update once i done.

Comment: It is not working . Controll is never come inside the item foreach loop.

Comment: Did you get incrementID ?

Comment: Yes i got the increment id

Comment: just print $orderData->getData() and check that array empty or data received.

Comment: No it is not empty . while i print $orderData->getData()['entity_id']; i got entity_id

Comment: while i take count count($orderData->getData()) it says 138  . But it is not come inside the "foreach($orderData->getAllItems() as $orderItem) " loop

Comment: while i print  "count($orderData->getAllItems())" is 0.  order data is not comming

Comment: It means order created. Items not added into order data.

Comment: @SammuSundar I am also facing the same issue. Did you solve this problem?